# How to define in Python a shared pointer to imported virtual class using cppyy

Tags: python, c++, cppyy

I have a virtual class in my code:

```cpp
namespace X
{
    class Y
    {


    public:
        /* CTOR */
        Y() {};

        /* DTOR */
        virtual ~Y() {};
        
        /* Initialization */
        virtual bool Init() = 0;

        virtual int Foo(void** ptr, size_t size) = 0;
        
        virtual int Foo2(void *ptr) = 0;


    private:

    };
}
```

I need to define the variable in python using cppyy:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<X::Y> tempValue = nullptr;
```

I have tried

```py
self.allocMgr = cppyy.gbl.MEMORY_ALLOCATOR.Allocator.__smartptr__()
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What is not working for you with `cppyy.gbl.std.shared_ptr['X::Y']()`?

Nominally, using `cppyy.gbl.std.make_shared` is the easiest approach (just as it is for C++), but in this case the template can not be directly instantiated because the class in the example is virtual. However, you can still create a typed `nullptr` using `cppyy.bind_object(cppyy.nullptr, cppyy.gbl.X.Y)` which can be used as an argument to aid implicit template instantiations.

Note that if `std::shared_ptr<X::Y> tempValue = nullptr;` is what you're looking for, and the Python code isn't obvious, then it's always possible to use `cppdef` as a workaround, eg.:

```
cppyy.cppdef("std::shared_ptr<X::Y> tempValue = nullptr;")
ptr = cppyy.gbl.tempValue
```